# Why are there many identical requests in auth_assignment in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

I'm developing a small admin panel on yii2. I use rbac and yii2-admin. There are a lot of identical requests in the debugger. 
These are:

```
SELECT * FROM `auth_assignment` WHERE` user_id` = '5'
```

I do not make queries to the tables of the rbac.

My action:

```
public function actionProduction(){

    $searchModel = new OrderSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['order_status' => 'production', 'production_user' => null]);

    //$active_order = $this->getActiveOrder(Yii::$app->user->getId(), Yii::$app->controller->action->id);

    return $this->render('userGrid', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'active_order' => $active_order,
        'to' => $to = 'packing'
    ]);

}
```

Comment: you are looged  with uer_id = 5?

Comment: Yes. It's current user

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are logged  as  user_di =5

the request you see in debugger

```
  SELECT * FROMauth_assignmentWHERE user_id= '5'
```

are performed  by rbac  yii2 module  for get the permission related  to the act user and store this permission for  check the accessing if needed

Comment: But it normal? I think there are a lot of queries.

Comment: @TimHoggarth it is normal until you set `cache` in `DbManager`. [DbManager - cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html#$cache-detail)

Comment: @Yupik Thank you